# How to set environment variable for ec2 user_data with terraform templatefile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I'd like to run `myscript.sh` with terraform templatefile. I set the variable `password` as environment variable in EC2. But, the script doesn't work well as I start the instance.

Here is files I wrote. Is is correct way to pass the environment variable under user_data?

- `myscript.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $password
# Continue to some procedures
```

- My terraform template

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ssm_parameter.amzn2_ami.value
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.key_pair.key_name
  user_data     = templatefile("./scripts/myscript.sh", {
    password = "********"
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myscript.sh` is missing `#!/bin/bash` and to refer to passed variables yo should use `${password}`. So it should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${password} > /tmp/test.txt
```

Also its better to test it by saving the `echo` into, for example, /tmp/test.txt. Otherwise you want see any output. But with the `/tmp/test.txt` you can login to the instance and check if `/tmp/test.txt` exists.

Also the script does not set any env variables.

Comment: `myscript.sh` is dummy script, real one has `#! /bin/bash`. I'll fix it. I appreciate it. BTW, Is there any wrong place on the terraform statement by your guess?

Comment: @SteaveStark It would be better if you provided actual script, as your dummy one is not representative of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  resource "aws_instance" "web" {
      ami           = data.aws_ssm_parameter.amzn2_ami.value
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      key_name      = aws_key_pair.key_pair.key_name
      user_data_base64     = base64encode(templatefile("./scripts/myscript.sh", {
        password = "********"
      }))
    }
```